# Mathematica how to turn list of lists into a single List

Tags: list, import, functional-programming, classification, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to run a simple text classifier experiment in Mathematica. The code below shows the setup for training the model;

```
B = Classify[{3 -> "The", 2 -> "Phrase", 1 -> "Best", 4 -> "Bad"}]
```

I have tested this on simple lists that I have manually put together and it works fine, the next step I'm looking to complete is to run this on a column of data that is imported from an excel sheet. I am not really familiar with Mathematica and I am more comfortable with Python. I am having trouble as it seems I cannot simply call a column and run a function on it. I believe my problem is that, when imported, the column is stored as a list of lists. how would I turn this into a single Text list so that I can try running the above. Also how would I store the output? I imagine I can create an object but again I am unfamiliar with this style of programming.

example of my data in excel below; literally single column, no headers

```
The Phrase
The Answer
The Phrases
Phrase
Answer
The Answer Phrase
The Answer Phrases
The Answers Phrase
The Question 
The Statement
Statement
Question
Questions
Statements
The Statements
Good
Bad
Neutral
Best
Better
The Best
The Bad
The Worst
Worst
The Offer
The Offers
Offer
```

once imported looks like the following;

```
`{{{"The Phrase"}, {"The Answer"}, {"The Phrases"}, {"Phrase"}, 
{"Answer"}, {"The Answer Phrase"}, {"The Answer Phrases"}, {"The 
Answers Phrase"}, {"The Question"}, {"The Statement"}, {"Statement"}, 
{"Question"}, {"Questions"}, {"Statements"}, {"The Statements"}, 
{"Good"}, {"Bad"}, {"Neutral"}, {"Best"}, {"Better"}, {"The Best"}, 
{"The Bad"}, {"The Worst"}, {"Worst"}, {"The Offer"}, {"The Offers"}, 
{"Offer"},....`
```

Comment: Try `Flatten[...your imported data...]` and see if that works for you

Comment: That ended up working, thanks for your help!

Comment: I suggest you post any further Mathematica questions in the mathematica.stackexchange.com site

Comment: note the outermost `{}` occurs because when you import excel it imports as a list of sheets. Whenever you import a single-sheet excel workbook start right away with `First@Import[file.xls]` to get rid of that.